# Is adding a link to a search term at the end of posts okay?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, hyperlinks

I just encountered an unusual way a user marks their posts. At the end of posts there is a link saying [IMSVG](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=IMSVG), [WCICON](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=WCICON), etc.

> [image]

Those led to a Stack Overflow search for that abbreviation:

> [image]

This seems to be a tagging mechanism, without the restrictions of actual tags. Is doing this okay?

I don't find these links very distracting, despite being slightly cryptic if you have not seen them before.

Comment: Regarding the link at the end of the answer: I consider that like a "thanks" under a post, if it doesn't add anything useful to the post, then it is noise and can/should be removed.

Comment: Interesting way to draw attention to ones own posts.. doesn't seem to be any different from other "signature, taglines, or greetings" as described in [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: @ccprog *"It is not what I asked"* - then edit it. *"edited in a way he considered not reflecting his views"* - I don't see why, it's their own words, I just reordered slightly for readability and removed a section not relevant to the question, but they're welcome to make further changes or ping me if they think I altered something crucial. *"not even considering to talk to him"* - how can we, given that they only posted a little while ago and have now deleted the answer we'd comment on to do so?

Comment: FWIW, I remember a similar discussion on another meta SE site since the same phenomenon has happened before on another SE site, but I couldn't find it now...

Comment: @AndrewT. SharePoint, by any chance? The user in question does the same thing there: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=top20

Comment: @jonrsharpe identifying the user is trivial, but finding the relevant meta post is surprisingly hard, either on their child meta or on MSE, but nothing found (or did my mind play a trick on me?)

Comment: @ccprog You're not responsible for the actions of other people. Nor the result of this post. I'm sorry if you feel you started something that turned into what you consider to be much more than what makes you feel comfortable. If you encounter something else in the future, an alternative is to raise a custom moderator flag on any of your own or any post of the user and explain your concerns.

Answer (score 67):

It's noise, and should be removed.

While the posts linked this way could be tangentially (or even directly) related to the post so annotated, the bespoke tagging system does not help a user not familiarized with it.

On questions, any link should be used to support and inform the question, and so that relationship needs to be made explicit and explained. "Related to", in the general sense, is already covered with links in the sidebar and the site's tagging system proper.

Similarly for answers, links should provide supporting material (and supporting only) that is helpful in answering the question at hand. Links to other posts that are only generally related to the discussed subject are a distraction and can be confusing for users who primarily are looking for answers to a specific question, not to follow a vague chain of links to read more on the question's subject.

Additionally, these links are not to individual posts, but to search queries. The result of the queries is dynamic and not dependable, so as linking strategy is particularly poor.

In essence, this adds nothing of value to a post, and thus distracts (the casual reader might think the link is actually of use, waste time trying to figure out the utility and relevancy of these search results).

If after removing the links the user rolls the edit back, one should flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @jscs A link to other questions using a certain term are only broadly related and not really helpful. If there is something useful one wants to link to, then link the actual post.

Comment: Not rolled back, as such, but apparently now trying to *hide it* in their posts: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63408313/revisions (revision 9).

Comment: @jonrsharpe If that happens again, then I would suggest to flag for moderator attention.

Comment: so if noise and distraction is discouraged, does that mean the side bar is going away?

Answer (score -46):

It's a creative tagging "system" using words unused on this site.

So my student **groups** can tag relevant information easily, without every time  having to edit older or other posts.

Been teaching it for the past 6 years. And I am sure they have thought others.

So plenty of other "group-tag" users around on SO. If you "kill" me there are dozens more who do use it now on SO.

But it doesn't work, or is visible, for those who don't know the tags.

So it is totally unclear who, or how many SO users use this **life-hack**.

To be fair: the life-hack credit goes to student Dave Swensons (not his real name)

Comment: And how does posting obscure abbreviations help with the problem you describe? Especially anyone who is not your student?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman you can roll-back the edit which may have conflicted with your intent, but the message jon left is good that it was getting off-topic. I voted to undelete because I think this thread needs to hear your side of the story as to why this custom tagging system is beneficial for the website at large or the posts specifically. I believe your intentions are good but I'm not sure I grasp how this obfuscation system is better than simply listing relevant other posts in English with a "see also: [list of relevant posts, possibly with explanation]".

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman English is not my first language either, but that doesn't justify your rudeness. Plus, even if someone edits your post while you  are in the middle of it, it doesn't mean that your edits go to garbage. They usually save.

Comment: Lastly, people can go through your profile to your other answers. There is no need for a signature.

Comment: I'm sorry you were impacted while still trying to revise it. Note if you're not yet happy with a post you can *not post it*; you have as many minutes as you like while it's a draft, but once it's live on the site it can and often will be edited by others per https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing.

Comment: "*I started with copy pasting whole "also see:" links*" - that seems to be the preferred approach, others doing the same. Instead of linking a whole "topic tag", link the concrete posts that are relevant in the post. The old answers can be edited to include new links. Yes, this is more work than a custom tagging system, but also much more useful.

Comment: We would really like that such links are more organic, rather than just tacked to every answer.

Comment: I am now following the guidelines the SO Moderators sent me this morning. If you think different, please contact them. I am obeying orders.

Comment: Why not create a github and organize your content there? You can link to your stack posts here, nothing stops you from doing that. Add a link to your profile.

Comment: Use "personal tagging systems" on your personal websites only. This is Stack Overflow, not Danny Engelman Overflow.

Comment: For what it's worth, your students should be able to find your posts pretty easily by just searching based on your username and a given tag plus relevant key words.

Comment: You are not following the guidance given by the mods. The guidance of the mods was to make it explicit that the link is to your own posts - both by stating this in the link description ("Others answers I wrote") and by including your userid in the search url. You are still trying to fly under the radar and creating a tagging system thats looks like it leads to generally useful answers, but primarily links to your own answers (by design, by how the search terms are chosen). Why not follow the directions you have been given to the letter? It still doesn't look like acting in good faith.

Comment: I think the original version of this answer had some legitimate points about the shortcomings of how SE aged, "In nearly every section answers from 10 years ago got way way more points/likes/upvotes than today.", "We all agreed it would be better if SO deleted old questions and answers.", it's absolutely true that points correlate to age, I've also ran into quite a bit of wrong information that's stuck there forever, because SO has no good mechanism to deal with it. I would say keep the original version, I don't think what's been cut out is irrelevant.

Comment: With that said, Danny, I would not recommend deleting this post, and it's not a huge issue, all it takes is a comment from the author for me to look at the whole revision history, it's easy enough to do.

Comment: As far as the issue at hand goes, it's pretty much widely accepted that posts on SE are not allowed to have unnecessary text, I can respect the idea of making a better curated set of answers when the voting system fails, but editors usually go by the original guidance for the site, which was "the system works, good answers rise to the top, remove anything that isn't a direct answer"; I'd recommend starting a blog (or [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) maybe) if you want a personally curated set of articles.

Comment: I've locked this for today. There's no point on the rollback war. I attempted to pick the best original version but I think this version is best suited.